# Convert tool to convert csv to Resx file for Localization of Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, localization, resx

I'm making app with using Xamarin.forms PCL.

I'm using localization of Xamarin, which is using resx files. 
I have documents for localization on google sheet.

What I want to try to do is converting csv file to each resx file. 
I'm using mac. (I also have a window machine)

Is there some converting tool or shell script for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you have [ResX Resource Manager](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b64e04c-e8de-4b97-8358-06c73a97cc68)  as a extension for `Visual Studio`, running `Windows`. I have a mac but I manage my resx files on `Windows` (Parallels) with this tool.

Its a very powerful tool.

> This tool provides central access to all ResX-based string resources
>   in your solution. You can quickly navigate through all resource files
>   and view the content in a well-arranged data grid. It makes it easy to
>   find untranslated strings or clean up orphaned entries. All strings
>   can be quickly edited in place, untranslated entries will be created
>   on the fly while typing. **Excel export and import lets you easily
>   exchange translations outside of Visual Studio**. Automated translations
>   can speed up you localization process.

Comment: Thanks again.! you again. I also have a mac. I have to use windows for that.

Comment: Yes you have. Try Parallels, its a good way. To use windows inside osx.